# How do I denormalize an ER-D into reporting views for end users?

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting, entity-relationship, denormalized

Link to ER-D: [D2L ER-D Diagram for Competency](https://documentation.brightspace.com/EN/insights/data_hub/admin/bds_competency.htm?tocpath=Administrators%7CBrightspace%20Core%20Analytics%7CAbout%20Brightspace%20Data%20Sets%7C_____12)

[image: ER-D Diagram for D2L Competency Data Set]

We have this data in an oracle database. It will go through IBM Framework Mangers which reflects all of the relationships in the ER-D, as well as add some security. Then it is available to our end users via Cognos, our reporting tool. I've been tasked with de-normalizing the data so that the end users see fewer reporting views/tables. For example, for this specific data set, the user currently sees all 6 competency related tables, along with 2 others (Users and Organizational Units). The goal is to make it easier for the end user by doing the joining together and instead of having 6 (or 8) tables, to have maybe 2 or 3 reporting views. I've never done this before, and assume that in creating the views, because none of them have zero cardinality (as in zero to many, one to zero or many, etc.) they are all inner joins. So first question, are these all inner joins? 2, Do I list columns that I want from each table, and then just join on the keys like this:

```
        select a.Activityid, a.Orgunitid, a.ActivityName, etc.
        b.Userid, b.LeraningObjectid, etc.
        from ComptencyActivities a
        inner join CompetnecyActivityResults b
        on a.ActivityId = b.ActivityId and a.OrgUnitId = b.OrgUnitid
```

3rd question, how do I figure out how many views to create? Would creating a single reporting view be an awful idea?

Also, I've done my best googling and have found sufficient advice on how to create ER-Ds and to normalize to a certain extent, but I'm having a hard time explaining how to de-normalize the data for reporting so any resources at all would be most appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: This is too broad for SO.  Research data marts since that's what it sounds like you're creating.  Without knowing more about the purposes of your report, I'd guess that CompActivityResults would be the source of a fact table (or view), and CompActivities, CompObjects, and even CompStructure (if you made a bunch of unpivited level columns) could all be denormalized into one dimension table.  Also do people REALLY need to look at the information in the logs - if not exclude it?  You could put relevant OrgUnits data and Users on the ActResults unless that adds to confusion.

Comment: Thanks so much for comment. In general, should the reporting goals drive the development of the views? We are in a bit of a chicken or egg situation in that most of the end users have never seen this data, so don't know how or what to report on. And I am sort of tasked with figuring how this data might make the most sense.

Comment: The starting point is to define your reporting requirements and work from there; there is no way to (successfully) forward engineer a reporting model from a normalised model. These 2 books are probably a good place to start: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Data-Warehouse-Lifecycle-Toolkit-2nd/dp/0470149779. https://www.amazon.co.uk/Agile-Data-Warehouse-Design-Collaborative/dp/0956817203